# How to detect if user is still on a promotional offer from StoreKit server notification

Tags: ios, webhooks, storekit

We currently have [server to server notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/enabling_app_store_server_notifications) setup on our server for our StoreKit implementation on iOS. We just recently introduced  [promotional offers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_promotional_offers_in_your_app) and are trying to gather more metadata on the subscription when we receive any of the webhook notifications.

What we are looking for specifically is a way to tell if a user is still on the promotional offer we gave them from the metadata that we receive from the [latest receipt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/latest_receipt_info) when a webhook is triggered, or from any other accessible data we can get from apple server side.

An example: We give a user a promotion (say they pay 99 cents for 3 months of access to our content) and they redeem it. When we receive the [DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/notification_type) webhook, we would like to know if their promo was still active when the user triggered it. Is there a way to gather this information just from the receipt data on our server? I see that the latest receipt has [is_in_intro_offer_period](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/is_in_intro_offer_period), but I don't think that applies to the promotional offer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks